# Problem parsing a list in batch

Tags: list, batch-file, tokenize

I am trying to extract tokens from a list of strings using a batch script, but for some reason it ignores my string if it contains an asterisk.

An example to illustrate this problem is as follows:

```
@echo off

set mylist="test1a,test1b"
set mylist="test2a,test2b*" %mylist%
set mylist="test3a,test3b" %mylist%

echo %mylist%

for %%a in ( %mylist% ) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in ( %%a ) do (
        echo %%i 
        echo %%j 
    )
)
```

I would expect this to print out all six tokens but instead it only prints test3a, test3b, test1a, and test1b, like it is ignoring the second string completely.

The placement of the asterisk within the second string doesn't seem to matter, but if I remove it everything works as I expect.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: I believe asterisk has functionality tied to it in batch files. Aliasing if I recall. Anyways, does it have to be an asterisk for your purposes? Could you replace it with a different character for your input? Is it absolutely necessary that you use an asterisk?

Comment: The same happens with a question mark ...

Comment: To do what I was planning it would need to be an asterisk. Basically the list contain commands to be executed, and for one of them the asterisk is part of the command arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The interpreter is trying to match a filename. If you change "test2a,test2b*"  by pp.* and create a file named pp.txt (same dir) your script will proces the contents of pp.txt

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get it to stop looking for a file and treat my strings as literals?

Comment: Nope. The "for" calls a child CMD.EXE that expands the list. As suggested by @Ben Burnett try to use another special char and replace it later by an asterisk post-processing the output file. Sorry.